# Replace an object with Null value Using Form Builder in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, bind, formbuilder

I am having trouble persisting a null which is already persisted with an object.

It throws the following error.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Requirements::setReplacedEmployee() must be an instance of MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Employee, null given, called in /var/www/MyProject/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 347 and defined in /var/www/MyProject/src/MyProject/EntityBundle/Entity/Requirements.php line 384
```

Initially i save the replacedEmployee object which could be null/object. But later on if i replace the object with a null while editing it throws the above error.

The below is my code from the controller.

```
try {
            if ($request->request->get('save') === 'Save') {

                $form->bindRequest($request); // this is the line which throws the above error

                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $requirementObj->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
                    $em->flush();
                    $request->request->set('requirementId', $requirementId);
                    return $this->displayAction($request);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the content in Requirements.php which is an entity file.

```
 /**
 * @var replacedEmployee
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"},targetEntity="Employee")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="replaced_employee_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $replacedEmployee;


 /**
 * Set replacedEmployee
 *
 * @param MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Employee $replacedEmployee
 */
public function setReplacedEmployee(\MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Employee $replacedEmployee)
{
    $this->replacedEmployee = $replacedEmployee;
}

/**
 * Get replacedEmployee
 *
 * @return MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Employee 
 */
public function getReplacedEmployee()
{
    return $this->replacedEmployee;
}
```

Can anybody Suggest a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have added some code as you asked

Comment: where did you call `Requirements::setReplacedEmployee()` in `Requirements.php`

Comment: Requirements is an entity file. which contains the function setReplacedEmployee(). The function is called automatically when the controller executes    $form->bindRequest($request);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't fully understand your question but, if you want to allow `null` values for the relation with `Employee` you should first edit the mapping (this maybe not necessary as `JoinColumn` should allow `null` values by default):

```
 /**
 * @var replacedEmployee
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"},targetEntity="Employee")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *     name="replaced_employee_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE",
 *     nullable=true
 *   )
 * })
 */
private $replacedEmployee;
```

After generating setters/getters Doctrine2 (if i remember correctly, starting from 2.2.1) should generate:

```
 /**
 * Set replacedEmployee
 *
 * @param MyProject\EntityBundle\Entity\Employee $replacedEmployee
 */
public function setReplacedEmployee(Employee $replacedEmployee = null)
{
    $this->replacedEmployee = $replacedEmployee;
}
```

Note that argument is optional (has `null` default value). Hope this helps.

Comment: Gremo, you just saved me a bunch of time =) Thanks! vote cast.