# Replace object for null in form symfony2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a similar problem to this:
[Replace an object with Null value Using Form Builder in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241333/replace-an-object-with-null-value-using-form-builder-in-symfony2)

I have an entity called Classification that has a ManyToOne Relationship to another entity called TypeClassification (one Classification belong to one type classification, or to none typeclassfication).

Classification.php:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeClassification", inversedBy="classifications", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $typeclassification;
```

TypeClassification.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Classification", mappedBy="typeclassification")
 */
private $classifications;
```

The form for Classification generated by default by symfony works, here is the code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('namejapanese')
        ->add('ldapid')
        ->add('typeclassification','entity', array('class' => 'ACMEMyBundle:TypeClassification','required' => false));
}
```

My problem relies in the entity choice field. I would like to allow Null value, and to set the relationship to Null.

As I said it works so far, but as soon as I add validation constraints to the Entity Classification, even if they are not related to the relationship at all:

validation.yml:

```
ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Classification:
#If I commend this constraints, everything works properly.
constraints:    
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: name, message: unique.name }
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: ldapid, message: unique.ldapid }
#For this properties doesn't matter if they are here or not
properties: 
    name:
        - NotBlank:
            message: not.blank
    namejapanese:
        - NotBlank:
            message: not.blank
    ldapid:
        - NotBlank:
            message: not.blank
```

Then I am unable to set the relationship back to Null. but If I comment the constraints part, then I can set it back to Null.

Why does that happen? And How can I make it to have both this validation and the ability to set the relationship to Null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because UniqueEntity constraint validator, which treats null's as duplicates. Create your own [validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) service and do checks there.

Comment: Thank you, it's good to know why, I guess I should have read more documentation. (I'm quite lazy to create the validator though (: )